# issue where an image positioned below a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, elementor

I've encountered an issue where an image positioned below a button is obstructing the ability to click the button. I attempted to address this problem by adjusting the z-index, but this resulted in the image being hidden.

My desired outcome is to keep the image in its current position while allowing clicks to interact with the button as intended. I'm seeking a solution that resolves this problem without hiding the image. Your assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bg4i.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd2Ng.png)

by adjusting the z-index, but this resulted in the image being hidden.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wHaF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create an invisible box with the functionality of a button positioned on your "Send Message" button, using a z-index higher than an arrow. In your result, the arrow will be displayed, and the button that you will be able to click.

**z-index hierarchy:**

*invisible button -> arrow -> "Send Message" button*